# Exchange - Custom Address List Will Not Update

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have a custom Address List in Exchange 2010 called 'All Users' that pulls all users that have Exchange mailboxes. There is one user that will not, for the life of me, show up in this list. When I preview the list filter results in EMC (EMC > Organization Configuration > Mailbox), it shows the user being picked up in the results. The list, however, is not getting picked up by my clients in the Outlook 'Search People' bar.

What troubleshooting commands/steps could I use to see why this one user is not being updated in the custom list? It seems that every Google post is more concerned with the Global Address list and not custom lists. I have tried to follow some of these steps without success.

Answer (score 0):

Does the same issue happen on the OWA?

If it happened on both Outlook Client and OWA, you could follow **Jason.Chao**’s suggestions in the thread [***Exchange Custom Address List not showing a user***](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/df29b78f-85b4-4de6-8992-48e493b4b376/exchange-custom-address-list-not-showing-a-user?forum=exchange2010), according to them, you could check and compare the properties of the problematic user and normal one to see if there are any differences in the **ADSI.EDIT/ADUC**.

If they have some different properties, you could change the properties of problematic users to those of normal users. If the properties of them have no problems, you could run the command **Get-AddressList | update-AddressList** to update the Address List, then check whether the issue still exists.

If the issue only happened on the Outlook Client, you could force updating your OAB in the Exchange Server by running the command **Get-OfflineAddressBook | Update-OfflineAddressBook** in the Exchange Server and enable **Cached Exchange Mode** on the client, then click "**Download Address Book**" to update address book and restart Outlook to check whether the user could be viewed and searched in the address book:

[image]
[image]

Hope everything goes well with you!